# Bootstrap modal box with inline edit PHP

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, simplemodal

Quick Question - 
Is it possible to have a modal window with inline edit(to be stored in DB)
I would be happy if that is available in bootstrap.
Yes or No? 
I nowhere see any examples having a list of records, and clicking the record that will open a modal box with inline edit.
Does my question sounds better?
Thansk,
Kimz

Comment: No friends to answer this query? :(

Answer (score 0):

You would need simplemodal.js : http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/, plus an inline editor, try tinymce, here is an example:http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/inline.php.